# How to implement /e modifier with PCRE2?

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

In Perl, we can do this

```
s/pattern/func($1)/e
```

Is there any convenient function that does the same thing with PCRE2, like

```
::pcre2_substitute_with_callback(
    re, // the compiled pattern
    pcuSubject, ccuSubject, // the subject and its length
    PCRE2_SUBSTITUTE_GLOBAL, // the substitute options
    matches,
    NULL, // the match context
    [](PCRE2_SPTR pcuMatched)->PCRE2_SPTR{ // the callback
        return "replacement";
    },
    pcuResult, &ccuResult
);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I think that there is no such convenience in `pcre2`. See the wrapper below though.

However, I believe that the replacement string for the call to [pcre2_substitute](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2_substitute.html) can be prepared without any particular restrictions. (I cannot test now.) The use of escape character (`$`) for capturing groups or pattern items is clearly specified but I don't see why one couldn't use that in a function/callback to form the replacement string.

That can then be wrapped in a method with a desired signature.

Some more documentation from `pcre2api` is at [Creating a new string with substitutions](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2api.html#SEC35)

---

There is a C++ wrapper [JPCRE2](https://neurobin.org/projects/softwares/libs/jpcre2/). It uses the `replace` method of [RegexReplace](https://docs.neurobin.org/jpcre2/classjpcre2_1_1select_1_1RegexReplace.html#a70785bd817e3c9f963e1b7a58f1dfb6f) for this purpose. However, about half-way through the main page it also informs us that

> There's another replace function (`jp::RegexReplace::nreplace()`) that takes a MatchEvaluator with a callback function. It's required when you have to create the replacement strings dynamically according to some criteria.
>
> The class `jp::MatchEvaluator` implements several constructor overloads to take different callback functions.

The page continues with a full example for usage of [jp::RegexReplace::nreplace()](https://docs.neurobin.org/jpcre2/classjpcre2_1_1select_1_1RegexReplace.html#a49b8ea766d07757f9bc6af28597ae545).

More detailed examples are offered in a test file in the distribution.

Comment: I think the quick answer is "No, there is no such convenient function in PCRE2". I just checked how JPCRE2 implements its jp::RegexReplace::nreplace(), and it uses pcre2_match(), which probably implies "Guys, you have to do it yourselves in the hard way. No convenient function." Thanks for telling me about JPCRE2. Have a nice day.

Comment: @Cody You are right, I did need to put a clear statement upfront. Thank you.

Comment: @Cody : `you have to do it yourselves in the hard way`, I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say, but it's like this: the `nreplace` method takes a function that returns a string where `$` is nothing special (literal). Though you can easily implement its behavior, e.g instead of returning `"a$0b"` from the callback, you can return `"a"+m[0]+"b"` and so on. And for the extended functionality of `pcre2_substitute`, you can use `if..else` which will probably be more readable.